# Pubsub pull subscriptions and concurrency

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am moving from push to pull subscriptions, and I've read the doc from Google on pubsub concurrency. Their example uses an Executor to subscribe to a topic. This is configured to have 4 threads with a default of 1 puller (2 pullers would therefore use 8 threads). When I startAsync, I think the client opens a streaming pull, which may stay open for a while (maybe). My question is, is there 1 executor per subscription, or is there a executor (and hence a threadpool) for all subscriptions. I have roughly 200 subscriptions, so 4 threads x 200 sounds wrong. How do then go about tuning? Do I simply start with an Executor with 10 threads handling all subscriptions and loadtest? If anyone has experience with this, it would be nice hear your thoughts.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Java client

Comment: You might have misunderstood the threading part. Threading is being implemented on the subscriber. Can you clarify more about your architecture? Or do you mean that you have 200 subscribers in a single subscription? If this is the case by default you have 4 threads per subscriber and it should be able to handle the processing of messages. You can adjust the threads per subscriber if you notice that the subscription has a lot of unacked messages (this can be viewed in Cloud Monitoring).

Comment: So 100 topics with 2 subscribers per topic. I'm wondering if subscribers share an ExecutorProvider or does each subscriber own its own executor? Their example was very simplistic with 1 topic and 1 subscriber. I am just curious about my thread count.

Comment: So maybe i shouldn't worry about. There example says..."Provides an executor service for processing messages. The default `executorProvider` used by the subscriber has a default thread count of 5." So each subscriber must own by default 5 threads. So 200 pull subscribers...that seems like a lot of threads.

Comment: Yes a subscriber has its own executor thus 5 threads per subscriber. Apologies for the confusion earlier with regards to the number of threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, each instance of the `Subscriber` has its own `executorProvider` and `systemExecutorProvider` that do create multiple threads. The default for the former creates [5 threads](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/e139eedacf0df497bbc97bde2cec94c79f2a0cab/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java#L414) and for the latter creates [`max(6, parallelPullCount)` threads](https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/blob/e139eedacf0df497bbc97bde2cec94c79f2a0cab/google-cloud-pubsub/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.java#L602).

One can override this behavior by setting these providers via the [`Subscriber.Builder.setExecutorProvider`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setExecutorProvider-com.google.api.gax.core.ExecutorProvider-) and [`Subscriber.Builder.setSystemExecutorProvider`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/com/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/Subscriber.Builder.html#setSystemExecutorProvider-com.google.api.gax.core.ExecutorProvider-) methods. You could provide the same `ExecutorProvider` to them, e.g. a [`FixedExecutorProvider`](https://googleapis.dev/java/gax/1.61.0/com/google/api/gax/core/FixedExecutorProvider.html).

However, if your intention is to pull messages from 200 subscriptions in the same job, you might be better off using [push subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) if you can. You would set up an https endpoint in your job and set the push endpoint on all 200 subscriptions to this same endpoint. All messages could be processed through the same codepath and you wouldn't have the overhead of a `Subscriber` instance for each one.